# How to get all the iterations in a list with none values included from a tweet?

Tags: python, dictionary, twitter, typeerror, nonetype

I  have set of tweets with 10 dictionaries in the list "tweets". Each dictionary has several tweets. The first tweet has 100 and the rest 9 have 15 each.
I need the location of each tweet in all the dictionaries. 
When I try to iterate the values from a list it shows this error.

```
if (type(tweets[j]['statuses'][k]['place']['name'])) != None:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The code I have used for the iteration is

```
for j in range (0,10):
    while j == 0:
       for k in range(0,100):
          st1 = tweets[j]['statuses'][k]['place']['name']
          print(st1)
```

I tried using "filter" to take out the "None" values, even that is not working. 
not every tweet has a location tagged to it. so it has None values. I need to print the locations of the tweets that are tagged.

Comment: can you place input here?

Comment: Could you give an example of the structure of your dictionaries within the list?

Comment: To avoid any dependency on the actual number of tweets, I'd probably change your `for` loop to be `for tweet in tweets`, then `for status in tweets.get('statuses', [])`. It'll make your code a bit easier to read

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check if the 'place' key is first available. I can see from your code that you are checking for ['place']['name']

Can you test your logic with the following filter logic without ['name']:

```
...
if (isinstance(tweets[j].get('statuses',[])[k].get('place', {}))) == dict:
...
```

Comment: I have used this. it enters the if loop and it is showing the same error again.

Comment: Then as suggested by @CNivs you can use the dict.get() call

Comment: `'place'` could be returned as some other type like `str`, which isn't subscriptable either. Just because it's not `None` doesn't mean it's a `dict`

Comment: True! so it's best to tighten up the check to validate it as a dict. Thanks @C.Nivs

Answer (score 0):

The twitter api returns json, which is a `dictionary` type in Python. When you are calling keys using `dict[key]` syntax, this is called `subscripting`. Now, nested calls on a dict object are dependent on that object being a dictionary type:

`dict[a][b]` relies on `dict[a]` being a dictionary with key `b` being available. If `dict[a]` is a different type, say `None` or `int`, it is *not* subscriptable. This means that there is not necessarily a `get` attribute for that type. A simple way to fix this would be the following:

```
check = tweets[j]['statuses'][k]['place']

if isinstance(check, dict):
    # do things
```

This makes sure that `check` is of type `dict` and therefore can be subscripted with a key

EDIT: Note that using `dict[key]` syntax is *not* safe against `KeyErrors`. If you want to avoid those, use `get`:

```
my_dictionary = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
my_dictionary['c']     # Raises KeyError: 'c' not in dictionary
my_dictionary.get('c') # returns None, no KeyError
```

It takes the form `dict.get(key, <return_value>)`, where `return_value` defaults to `None`

To make your program a bit more readable and avoid the inevitable infinite loop, ditch the `while` loop:

```
# This will get individual tweets
for tweet in tweets:

    # Returns all statuses or empty list
    statuses = tweet.get('statuses', [])
    for status in statuses:
        if not isinstance(status, dict):
            continue # will jump to next iteration of inner for loop

        # Will be a name or None, if empty dict is returned from place
        name = status.get('place', {}).get('name')
        if name:
            print(name)
```

Comment: This worked but it sent it to an infinte loop. The same output kept looping on the console.

Comment: This is because `j` is not being updated in your `while` loop. It will always be `0`

Comment: @SB check the edit to my question, this will avoid your infinite loop

Comment: tweets is a list. we can't use get attribute on a list

Comment: typo, `tweet.get` is what was meant

Comment: name = status.get('place', {}).get('name')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Ah, so in this case, one of your `status` objects is `None`

Comment: There is no way around this?

Comment: There's always a way around, it's just additional checks. See newest edit

Comment: I figured out the answer, check it out. Thanks for your help. @C.Nivs

Answer (score 0):

```
for element in tweets:
    for s in element.get('statuses'):
       place = s.get('place')
       print(place['name'])
```

This fixed it.